# Appending to BODY element

Tags: asp.net, response.write

Just before (or during) rendering page I would like to append a piece of code (java script). However when I try to add new LiteralControl via Page.Controls property I get an error:

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

How to get round that issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid that problem do the following:

1. Add a `<asp:Placeholder id="Placeholder1" runat="server" />` control in your ASPX
2. In code behind add the control to the Controls collection of that placeholder:

   Placeholder1.Controls.Add(myControl);

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the `LiteralControl` to your markup and set its `Text` property from code-behind.

**EDIT:**

Another (and probably more correct) option is to use [`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338357.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work: I have a BasePage class which inherits from Page class. And I want to do it in my base class (I don't use master pages though).

Comment: Ok thanks. However... What if I want to add HTML code, not java script ? :))